# Taking advantage on typescript type system to improve my code

Tags: typescript

I was curious if TypeScript can help me on this question.

My project has text messages, media messages, keyboard messages and event messages.

```js
interface Message {
  kind: 'text' // can be `text`, `media`, `keyboard` or `event` 
}
```

Each type has their own properties, like image has the preview for example.

Currently what we have is something like this

```js
export type MessageKind = 'text' | 'media' | 'keyboard' | 'event'
```

```js
export interface MessageSchema {
  id: string // common to all messages
  kind: MessageKind // common to all messages
  room: string // common to all messages

  // now come the specific fields and sadly all optionals.
  filename?: string // specific of the "kind" media
  caption?: string // specific of the "kind" media
  mimetype?: string // specific of the "kind" media
  orientation?: 'portrait' | 'landscape'  // specific of the "kind" media

  rows?: number // specific of the "kind" keyboard
  columns?: number // specific of the "kind" keyboard

  price?: number // specific of the "kind" event
  balance?: number // specific of the "kind" event
  charged?: boolean // specific of the "kind" event
}
```

How can I design a better solution without abusing the nullable types?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an intersection type for the common fields then a union for all the kind-specific ones:

```js
export type MessageSchema = {
    id: string;
    room: string;
} & (
    | {
          kind: "text";
      }
    | {
          kind: "media";
          filename: string;
          caption: string;
          mimetype: string;
          orientation: "portrait" | "landscape";
      }
    | {
          kind: "keyboard";
          rows: number;
          columns: number;
      }
    | {
          kind: "event";
          price: number;
          balance: number;
          charged: boolean;
      }
);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it should be accepted as the answer to the question.

Comment: You may wish to provide a documentation link for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) also